# Submit button with file download

Tags: php, html, css

I want code for submit button, when we click on that submit button it should save the data and a file should be downloaded, both the action's should happen on single click.

can you help me?

Comment: You need to post your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do

HTML code

```
<form method="post">
<input type=submit value=submit />
</form>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']{
    echo '<script>window.open("http://yourfiletodownload");</script>';
    //here your code to save data
?>
```